# wp7 record and play video concurrently

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, video, recording, playing

I would like to record and play a video on Windows Phone 7 simultaneously.

For recording I use:

```
CaptureSource captureSource = new CaptureSource();
VideoBrush videoBrush = new VideoBrush();
videoBrush.SetSource(captureSource);
uxScreen.Fill = videoBrush;
captureSource.Start();
```

For playing:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream isoVideoFile;
isoVideoFile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("aaa.mp4",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
uxScreen2.SetSource(isoVideoFile);
```

Separately they work like the should, but if I try to play and record simultaneously I've got an error "NotSupportedException was unhandled" 0x80131515

Is it possible to play and record a video in the same time or maybe it's hardware restricted?